# How can I make OBS' virtual cameras available to BlueJeans?

Tags: windows, obs-studio, bluejeans, virtual-webcam

I use  [OBS-VirtualCam](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.539/) to create virtual cameras. Skype see them but BlueJeans don't (= OBS-VirtualCam's virtual cameras are not listed in BlueJeans). 
How can I make OBS' virtual cameras available to BlueJeans?

I use OBS 23.2.1 64-bit,  [OBS-VirtualCam 2.0.2](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-virtual-cam/releases), BlueJeans 2.14.4561.0 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

---

Cam is running:

[image]

however BlueJeans doesn't see it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but it's still an issue. When you install the VirtualCam plugin, the BlueJeans client doesn't recognize it.

It does however work with Firefox. When you join a BlueJeans meeting, Firefox will ask you which camera you want to give permission for BlueJeans to use, including the virtual OBS cameras.

Just make sure to NOT click the "remember this choice" (or something alike), as it somehow doesn't get access to the virtual cameras the next time and you have to clear the custom site settings.

Comment: Thanks good to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can select one of the OBS virtual cameras as input in WebcamMax, then select WebcamMax as input in BlueJeans.

WebcamMax configuration:

[image]

[image]

BlueJeans configuration:

[image]